# JEE does Rest Endpoint config overtake flow of control from JSF?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, soa

In JEE as described by the oracle docs , the container to which the application is deployed will generally intercept client requests and based on the application configuration route them to a component living in the web tier, (JSF, Servlet, JSP, Rest Endpoint).

The below diagram illustrates the relationship fairly well.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/webapp001.htm

If we are implementing a rest configuration using rest endpoints, according to oracle, those rest endpoints are "web components", therefore the container will route user requests, say for example index/users/1 to a rest endpoint for the users with a query param of 1 for an id.

How does this then integrate with another web component such as JSF? Does the rest endpoint configuration essentially hijack the routing to JSF? Is the rest endpoint also responsible for including a specific view component in it's http response to the client? I was under the impression that in SOA the rest end point merely provides a service to retrieve data based on a restful state, to present to the current model for the current view.

For example , in my interpretation it should be something like this instead.

```
Client Request ----> JSF servlet------>call rest endpoint
Gets new page  <-- Update Model <-------end point talks to DB and returns data
           and spit out new html page
```

Am I misinterpreting what the oracle docs are saying specifically when they include the rest configuration as a web component?

Answer (score 2):

In your web.xml you can set up different deployment descriptors for the different components. So you can have requests routed to different components based on the root context. Eg www.site.com/rest/service can be routed to a rest API based on the context of "/rest" and you could have other requests routed to your JSF servlet with a context of /faces".

[This link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml) explains it pretty well.